# Dupliate code in controller to be used in other controller

Tags: spring, controller

I noticed that there is some Code in a Controller that I have to use as well in another Controller. So this would be the scenerio.

class ControllerA{

```
@PostMapping("/testcase")
public RedirectView saveResult(Model model, @ModelAttribute)
{
        func();

}


public static func()
{
    //Code Comes here
}
```

}

class ControllerB{

```
  @PostMapping("")
  {
       ControllerA.func();
  }
```

}

So as you can see I put the duplicate Code in a static public method so it will also be accissible in ControllerB . Do you think this is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I would say this isn't advisable. I would prefer to put shared functionality within a base controller class you could inherit from.

Here is an example: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-abstract-controller-example/

Depending on the kind of problem you could also opt to solve your problem with a shared helper class or put shared functionality within a service layer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is a good Idea as it introduces a dependency (direct coupling) between the two controllers, which goes against the concept of low coupling and high cohesion, as both controllers should be functioning independently.

Think of it this way: When somebody has to change the method in `ControllerA`, would it feel naturally necessary for him to check other usages?

Most likely, the answer is no, as controller methods are usually only called by the web framework or other methods of the controller itself.

**So how should it be done?**

You could either introduce a controller utility class which holds the needed method or move the method to the service layer, if this makes sense. Or you could just leave the code duplicated in two files. Which solution is better depends on several factors:

- Is it crucial that the method always behaves in the same way for all classes?
- How likely are the implementations to stay the same for both classes?
- How likely is the method to be reused in other classes?
- How much code is duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a abstract class that contains all your duplicate methods and it cannot be instantiated:

```
    public abstract class AbstractController
      {

          public void func()
             {
                     //Code Comes here
             }

      }
```

And

```
   class ControllerA extends AbstractController
{

    @PostMapping("/testcase")
    public RedirectView saveResult(Model model, @ModelAttribute)
       {
            func();

       }

 }
```

And

```
    class ControllerB extends AbstractController
{

      @PostMapping("")
      {
          func();
      }
}
```